# Deleting a User in MS Dynamics 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I know that deleting users in Dynamics CRM is unsupported. However, this is just a test environment that we have put up and now it needs to be 'formated'. I have managed to delete all the cases, appointments ect...

Just want to know if there is a way of deleting the users as these users have address then the address that they have is being used on a 'User Locations' dashboard, so even if I disable the users they still appear on this dashboard. Is there a way to stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little investigation i found two ways that got around the problem of the address being displayed on the dashboard for disabled users.

Sticking to guidelines I did not DELETE the users from dynamics.

SOLUTION 1 - Good Fix

I amended the oData query that the JavaScript file used to get the data from dynamics. This then filtered the data that I was getting back from dynamics by using the isDisabled schema field name.

SOLUTION 2 - Bad Fix
I went to into each of the users that had an address and replaced the current address with the value of 'null' for each field as this is not picked up by Bing Maps when making a geoCode request.

Hope that helped if anybody reads this.